# Is there a crack in everything, where the light gets in?

Tags: imperfection

Note: This question was seriously cut down in an effort to avoid closure.

In [Anthem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8-BT6y_wYg) Leonard Cohen says:

```
    Forget your perfect offering
    There is a crack in everything
    That’s how the light gets in
```

I am looking for philosophical explorations of this idea, for philosophers that have discussed this relationship between fragility and knowledge. **Would you know of any philosopher who has written about that?**

PS: I am aware of Hegel's Master-Slave dialectic and am trying to find it online. If you have a link, kindly post.

Comment: There are a lot of unwarranted assumptions and auto contradiction in the formulation of your question that actually reveal the vacuity of a concept like "perfection".

Comment: [Hegel, Lord and Bondsman](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/hegel/works/ph/phba.htm), a.k.a. master-slave.

Comment: Thank you @Conifold

Comment: This relates not to power-weakness, but to human imperfection as a distinction:"*The individual man, since his separate existence is manifested only by ignorance and error, so far as he is anything apart from his fellows, and from what he and they are to be, is only a negation. This is man, proud man, most ignorant of what he's most assured, his glassy essence.*" [Peirce, Some Consequences of Four Incapacities](https://arisbe.sitehost.iu.edu/menu/library/bycsp/conseq/cn-frame.htm).

Comment: People who write about Nonduality.

Comment: i think this is a worthwhile question. reminds me a little of zizek.

Comment: Why is the question tagged 'Isreal'? Isreal is indirectly referenced but the question isn't about Isreal per se.

Comment: why does israel have its own tag? i blame the 20th century for everything that has happened...

Comment: @MarcoOcram Sorry, new here. The question is indeed much broader than Israel but it "hit" me in the context of the current events, as explained. I can add the tag "palestine" for balance, or delete "israel" if you think that's the most appropriate.

Comment: @ScottRowe Anyone in particular?

Comment: @Conifold Thank you again, started reading.

Comment: fwiw, i think of non-duality as writing as best personified in dogen's extensive record and the shobogenzo. it always strikes me at first as completely wrong, until you think about it @ScottRowe wdyt?

Comment: Not Alan Watts, too glib.

Comment: @Olivier5 I would just delete the tag.The question isn't about Palestine either, so no reason to add that tag. All the best.

Comment: @MarcoOcram Done. Added "lord-and-bondsman", which seemed more topical.

Comment: The value of an open world vs. a closed top-down perfection is central to a lot of recent theological work in progressive Christianity. Three key words to use to search would be Open, Relational, and Process theologies. The process theologians are vectoring off the philosophic thinking of Whitehead and Hartshorne. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/process-philosophy/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Hartshorne#:~:text=The%20intellectual%20movement%20with%20which%20Hartshorne%20is%20associated,Greek%20Heraclitus%20and%20in%20Eastern%20philosophy%20in%20Buddhism. I am currently reading: ht

Comment: One might interpret Kant's two-worlds/two-standpoints, or then the gap between them, as such a fissure. I am also reminded of the Zohar's talk of broken vessels, of shards of something "around" God.

Comment: Even a totalitarian regime is a utopia only for some, and a Helheim for others, thus exposing its own crack.

Comment: "Man wishes concord; but Nature knows better what is good for the race; she wills discord. He wishes to live comfortably and pleasantly; Nature wills that he should be plunged from sloth and passive contentment into labor and trouble, in order that he may find means of extricating himself from them." Kant in [Idea for a Universal History from a Cosmopolitical Purpose](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Idea_for_a_Universal_History_from_a_Cosmopolitan_Point_of_View)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This concept is hard to find explicitly in mainstream Western secular philosophy, but it's arguably **implicit in Wittgenstein** ("What we cannot speak about we must pass over in silence") despite his perfectionism. You might also perceive it as **implicit in Gödel**'s famous exploitation of paradox in order to invalidate the project to perfect mathematics. Arguably this same idea of imperfections leading to larger truth is also at **the root of the Socratic technique of *aporia***, where the irresolvable flaws of an argument force the reader into a moment of pure insight (Zen *koans* arguably use a similar technique).

In specific reference to the idea of **weakness as power**, it's easier to find in Eastern philosophies. You can discern it in the Taoist concept of the usefulness of emptiness (https://tao-in-you.com/a-pot-is-useful-for-its-emptiness/), as well as in the Japanese political philosophy of the "empty center," where the person who seems to have the most power (the Emperor) is actually the most powerless.

You excluded prophets and poets, but an explicit version of this concept has a long tradition in **Christian theology.** The most cogent formulation is perhaps Paul's *Second Letter to the Corinthians* where he says

> And He said to me, “My grace is sufficient for you, for My strength is made perfect in weakness.” Therefore most gladly I will rather boast in my infirmities, that the power of Christ may rest upon me. Therefore I take pleasure in infirmities, in reproaches, in needs, in persecutions, in distresses, for Christ’s sake. For **when I am weak, then I am strong**.
> *2 Corinthians 2:9-10*

You can see echos of this in Tertullian, and much later in **Kierkegaard** (https://mbird.com/theology/the-weaker-the-stronger-according-to-kierkegaard/). The idea here is that human weakness invites us to rely instead on God's strength--the weaker person is more fortunate because of their greater understanding of the necessity of God (contrast here with Penn Jillette's statement of atheistic moral sufficiency https://www.reddit.com/r/atheism/comments/1biwal/penn_jillette_hits_the_nail_on_the_head_again_i/).

Comment: Yes, this is an eminently Judeo-Christian idea. The inversion of natural values. He who lowers himself will be exalted, and he who exalt himself will be lowered, say the Gospels. And yet, there's something slightly disgusting in the systematic use of this idea by Kierkegaard in the link you shared. Now I think I understand Nietzsche's condemnation of slave mentality better: it's one thing to appreciate the virtues of weakness, another thing entirely to wallow in it like Kierkegaard does.

Comment: I would like to add that this dialectic between imperfection and knowledge could be seen as central to philosophy. A philosopher is someone who shouts out, said Deuleuze, because (s)he is missing something vitally important, or seeing something scandalously important that others don't seem to mind. Philosophy is really the desire for wisdom, and one only desires what one lacks.